# Wireless printing from Android phone

Tags: applications, stock-android

I have a samsung galaxy prevail through boost mobile what kind of printer do I need and how do I print from my smartphone wirelessly?

Comment: You can use pretty much any printer – and chose from a large set of [Printing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_print) – basically 3 groups: [Vendor specific Printing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_print#group_52), [Vendor overlapping Printing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_print#group_53), and [Cloud Printing](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_print#group_54). With the latter group, keep your "privacy wishes" in front of you – everything you print goes to the cloud then.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Cloud Print

Generally, you'd want to use [Google Cloud Print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/) compatible printers. The full list of Cloud Print ready printers is available [here](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html).

If you're stuck without one of these printers (i.e. a *classic* printer), [you've still got options](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en&rd=1):

> Before connecting your classic printer, confirm if you have:
>
> - Google Chrome
> - Windows or Mac computer
>
> And if you’re using Windows XP, the Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3).
>   Then, follow the steps below to enable the Google Cloud Print connector:
>
> 1. **Open Google Chrome.**
>      In a new tab, open `chrome://devices`
>      You’ll see a list of devices already registered with Google Cloud Print, and new devices available on the network.
> 2. Under "Classic printers,” **click Add printers**.
>      You'll see a confirmation that Google Cloud Print has been enabled.
> 3. To learn more, **click Manage your printers**.

To connect classic printers in a business or school environment, use the Cloud Print Connector service on Windows or Linux.

After adding your Cloud Print ready printer, use the [Google Cloud Print app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint) to [start printing](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/3153824?hl=en&vid=1-635759126510013996-2950415502)

In versions of Android newer than 4.4, the app isn't necessary:

> 1. **Open the page you want to print** in its app (Photos, Chrome, etc).
> 2. On the app, **click Options**.
> 3. **Select Print**.